# Backstage Publish Repo Azure Devops Server

Tags: azure, scaffold, backstage

We are using Azure DevOps Server 2020 (On-Prem). We want to create repositories from backstage scaffolder template. We integrated our repository on app-config.yaml file and succesfully added component for kind: Template. Now we want to use this template to create and publish this repo to Azure. But, we couldn't manage it we are having "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')" error on Publish stage

Here is my "template.yaml" file;

apiVersion: scaffolder.backstage.io/v1beta3
kind: Template
metadata:
name: v1beta3-demo
title: Test Action template
description: scaffolder v1beta3 template demo
spec:
owner: backstage/techdocs-core
type: service

input
parameters:
- title: Fill in some steps
required:
- name
properties:
name:
title: Name
type: string
description: Unique name of the component
ui:autofocus: true
ui:options:
rows: 5
- title: Choose a location
required:
- repoUrl
properties:
repoUrl:
title: Repository Location
type: string
ui:field: RepoUrlPicker
ui:options:
allowedHosts:
- tfsmaster.tech.com.tr

steps:
- id: fetch-base
name: Fetch Base
action: fetch:template
input:
url: ./skeleton
values:
name: ${{ parameters.name }}

```
- id: publish
  name: Publish
  action: publish:azure
  input:
    allowedHosts: ['tfsmaster.tech.com.tr']
    description: This is ${{ parameters.name }}
    repoUrl: ${{ parameters.repoUrl }}

- id: register
  name: Register
  action: catalog:register
  input:
    repoContentsUrl: ${{ steps['publish'].output.repoContentsUrl }}
    catalogInfoPath: '/catalog-info.yaml'
```

Here is the full error; are we missing something?

2023-12-25T12:20:14.000Z Beginning step Publish22023-12-25T12:20:15.000Z TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')3    at /app/node_modules/azure-devops-node-api/VsoClient.js:124:524    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

I tried to create a repository from template. It was not created.